# Sklearn and hadoop import error

Tags: python, hadoop, scikit-learn, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to implement some NLP stuff using streaming mapreduce for some undergraduate work. I feel like I have most of the code correct, however I'm running into some problems getting my mapper to use sklearn modules. I'm using anaconda and I've tested everything locally and it works fine. I had a similar issue with a virtual machine I was using (A udacity tutorial) but it would fail on anything that was imported from anaconda, such as scipy or numpy. My current mapper has no problem using those, it's only when sklearn is imported it crashes. Specifically, from the log file:

> File "/..././tokenize_mapper.py", line 12, in 
>       from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>   ImportError: No module named sklearn.feature_extraction.text

My mapper looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import scipy.sparse
import numpy
import cPickle as pickle
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer #breaks here

for line in sys.stdin:
    #Some Stuff
```

I can get it to work fine, as long as I exclude the import sklearn line. I'm curious if anyone has an suggestions for why this would be? I would understand if none of the libraries that came with anaconda were working. I'm running hadoop (In pseudo distributed mode) 2.4.0 on a mac with 10.9.3, my sklearn version is '0.14.1' and I'm using python 2.7

Comment: You "tested everything locally", then from where are you running this `.py` that is giving you this error?

Comment: Well, did you install scikit-learn on the worker nodes?

Comment: @GoBrewers14 I tested them by calling the mappers and reducers as scripts (./mapper.py < test.txt). And larsmans, this is going to sound terribly stupid, but I wasn't aware I had to if it's using my python environment (And it seems to be, because it can use scipy and etc.)

Comment: It turns out I was mistaken. OSX does infact come with some pre-installed python modules. The fix was as simple as installing sklearn into the normal /usr/bin/python version of python.